# Parallel windings on a solenoid coil

Tags: inductor, solenoid, coil

Suppose I have a fixed voltage supply of 10 V and I need to get 20 amp-turns from my solenoid coil but my solenoid coil with 10 turns is 10 ohms, so I am getting 10V/10 ohms = 1A,  1A * 10 turns = 10 amp turns.

Can I take my coil and instead take the wire and cut it in half and wind both halves at the same time.  So now I have two 5 turn coils in parallel, each with 5 ohms resistance.  So I do the calculation and get
10V/5 ohms = 2A for each coil, 2A * 5 turns = 10 amp-turns for each coil, 
So now I have 20 amp-turns total on my coil.

Therefore making my solenoid 4 times stronger?

Is this right or am I missing some fundamental law of electromagnetism?

Thank you

Comment: "get 10V/5ohms = 2A for each coil, 2A*5Turns = 10Amp Turns for each coil, So now I have 20Amp Turns " somehow your math here does not add up. You have 10 "amp turns". You double the amps, and halve the turns.

Comment: But theoretically the approach should work..

Comment: @PlasmaHH, no, the OP multiplies the current by 4, while halving the turns. Each 5-turns winding will conduct 2 Amps, 4 Amps in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"stronger" is not very scientific, it could mean many things. If you measure strength in Amp*Turns, your solenoid is twice as strong after the modification. If (as I understood from comments) you're considering the electromagnetic pull force which is proportional to (I * N)<sup>2</sup>, then your new solenoid is 4 times as strong.

Also, if your solenoid is small enough, its core may go into [saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_%28magnetic%29) before you reach maximum current. Increasing the current further in that case will have practically no effect on the pull force.

Comment: I am looking at DC only for this question. I am looking to increase the pull strength of my solenoid.  Right now I am using the force equation.  http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Magnets/Solenoid-Force-Calculator.phtml   Also looking at the power I am putting into the solenoid.  Originally power = V^2/R = 10*10/10 = 10 Watts,  my new coil has power = 10*10/2.5 = 40 Watts.

Comment: Then it's 4 times like you said. The pull force is proportional to I squared, so if you double the current the force will increase 4-fold.

Comment: If the solenoid was limited by its heat dissipation, either it will now melt, or you will have to halve the voltage to keep its power dissipation the same as before. Which halves the current, maintaining exactly the same strength as the original.

Comment: @BrianDrummond you could still use the said solenoid to develop the full strength for a limited time, then wait for it to cool down, rinse, repeat.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Absolutely true.  On the other hand, when the core material reaches magnetic saturation, more ampere-turns won't further increase the pull.

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's a valuable comment. I added this remark to my answer.

Comment: You say that your computation won't hold for AC but actually, it does so maybe you need to refine what your are saying. See my answer for what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Andyaka You're right. I took electronics classes about ten years ago and managed to forget that L ~ N², while still remembering about coupling. BTW, you should rotate your hat =)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have calculated the right result. 5 turns with 2A is 10 AT therefore, 2 parallel windings of 5 turns will take 4A and you then have 20 AT.

As an aside, for AC applications, the two parallel windings of 5 turns behave like one 5 turn winding and, because of this, the inductance quarters compared to when you had 10 turns. This is because inductance is proportional to turns-squared and the two windings are assumed to couple perfectly.

Ignoring resistance, current would be 4 times higher at any particular frequency and this would also mean that the net (RMS) ampere turns have doubled: -

Original turns = 10 at 1A RMS. New turns = 5 at 4 times the current.